# Session is getting timed out in 1 minuites

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am working on a project the problem happening is in my local system the session is working fine but in the testing server the session is not working sometimes even login is not happening ...sometimes after login it is working for few minuites then getting logged out and sometimes the session is is getting timed out at 1-2 minuites .. Please Suggest

Answer (score 3):

@rajender i had similar problem and i found that my hosting is on shared server and shared server just provide 100 mb ram and my app is rebooted after some time and all session variables were cleared so i used session handling using sqlsrever.You can try solution in following link. it solved my problem.

[Session handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394357/asp-net-4-0-storing-session-in-sqlserver)

Comment: Thanks What i did was hosted it on a different server and its working fine it seems some kind of a server error was occouring

Comment: may be possible but i had witness similar issue and found that server allocate very lil resources for app to work the sol link i have shared work like magic. before getting this done. i also changed my server to better one it worked but again that dhould not be the sol.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting session timeout inside SessionState in web.config as Amritpal pointed out

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
```