# Generic Lists in a HttpSessionState stored in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session-state

I'm working on a aspx application (C#), where I'm using `HttpSessionState` to save different objects in code behind between view changes. Some of these objects containts generic lists (`List<T>`), but those lists doesn't seem to be saved when I'm using an SQL database to store the state (`sessionState mode = "SQLServer"`). All other properties in the object gets saved, but when I try to retrieve the list, I get empty lists.

The funny thing is that it all works fine if I use `sessionState mode = "InProc"`.

My classes have the `Serializable` attribute. I'm running C#/.NET 4.0.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Just to clarify with some code (not verbatim!).

I have the classes I want to save (instances of) to my Session State:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public List<MyOtherClass> Property3 { get; set; }
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public string AnotherProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string AnotherProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my Code Behind - one action saves objects of the previous classes:

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
        {
            Property1 = "One string",
            Property2 = "One other string",
            Property3 = new List<MyOtherClass>() { new MyOtherClass() { AnotherProperty1 = "One", AnotherProperty2 = "Ohter" } }
        };

        HttpContext.Current.Session["MyKey"] = myClass;
    }
```

...and another action will retrieve that object:

```
    public void MyOtherMethod()
    {
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyKey"];

        int c = myClass.Property3.Count; // Will be 0!!
    }
```

So `myClass.Property1` and `myClass.Property2` will hold the strings I set previously, but `myClass.Property3` is an empty list.

Comment: did you configured your application to use sql server for session state? see this post on ho wto do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394357/asp-net-4-0-storing-session-in-sqlserver

Comment: Yes. This application is hosted on a web server with multiple sites, and basically all other sites on the server uses SQL for the session state. Also - remember that in my application, it stores all the data in the objects except for the lists (which are initialized, but empty)!

Comment: can you show your code where you store and read list object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are describing could happen if you

- Store a reference to an object in that generic list that is valid when you store it, but
- the reference is no longer valid on subsequent requests.

An example would be storing a reference to a control from the `Page.Controls` collection - this reference would not be valid if you try to retrieve it on another postback.  In fact, the reference may just be cleaned up by garbage collection (thus why your list appears to be empty).

Without seeing your actual code, it's tough to say for sure (although your example code does a great job of clarifying what you mean).  But this seems likely to me.

Comment: I basically ending up re-factorizing the code to avoid this whole issue, but I think that you are right about the references. The actual code is hard to provide here, since it is "scattered" over many methods and classes. But when I was looking in more to the code I saw some places where I potentially might get the problem with references that you are describing.

Comment: @Superhubert Great!  Yeah, you're approach (refactoring) was probably the best approach =)  I'm glad I could provide some insight.